# Old Hunter Henriett & the Witch of Hemwick

Tags: bloodborne

I have been ignoring Vicar Amelia for some time as I went to Old Yharnam and Hemwick Charnel Lane instead. I have opened both locked gates in Cathedral Ward, allowing me to summon Henriett:

[image: Old hunter Henriett]

However, I have heard rumours she vanishes after defeating the Witch Of Hemwick.

Is there any truth to the matter?

I do know I need Insight to summon her (I currently have 12 before the Witch of Hemwick boss fight) and have a few Madman's Knowledge stashed just in case…

Comment: From the Bloodbourne Wiki:

`Can be summoned for the fights with Vicar Amelia and Ludwig the Accursed/The Holy Blade.`
You can find Henriett's summon for Vicar Amelia near the ladder that leads to the numbing mist in Cathedral Ward, just up the stairs outside the front door of Oedon Chapel. She can also be summoned for Ludwig, to the left just down the stairs beside the Nightmare Church lamp. `doesn't mention anything about her dissappearing after the Witch fight, however there are a few other threads of people reporting they are unable to summon her in NG+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once requirements are met (wearing specific rune, doing something - in your case you've already opened gates), summons in location are available until boss of that location is defeated. For Old Hunter Henriett this location boss is Vicar Amelia and not Witch of Hemwick.

In DLC location summoning Confederate hunters will prevent one from summoning Henriett, but for Vicar Amelia there are no other summons.

And don't worry about insight, you need only 1 to summon.

Comment: Confirmed in last night play…  I was worrying for nothing. Old Hunter Henriett is a good helper to defeat Vicar Amelia.